# NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory when trying to load in Zip file on Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to experiment on Google Colab with CNNs and GANs using the CelebA dataset. I'm trying to load in the data in PyTorch using `ImageFolder` like so:

```
# Loading in data

dataroot = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/celeba/img_align_celeba.zip"


dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root = dataroot,
                           transform = transforms.Compose([
                                       transforms.Resize(image_size),
                                       transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),                    
                           ]))
```

Bear in mind, I've fully mounted my drive and have the celeba.zip file on my G-Drive. However, when trying to execute the above, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ebc6bb8ab4bd> in <module>()
     10                                        transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
     11                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
---> 12                                        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
     13                            ]))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in find_classes(directory)
     38     See :class:`DatasetFolder` for details.
     39     """
---> 40     classes = sorted(entry.name for entry in os.scandir(directory) if entry.is_dir())
     41     if not classes:
     42         raise FileNotFoundError(f"Couldn't find any class folder in {directory}.")

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/celeba/img_align_celeba.zip'
```

Unless I'm missing something, my `dataroot` variable is the correct directory as it's the correct path to the zip containing the images. I've attempted to unzip the files by doing:

```
!cp "{dataroot}" .
!yes|unzip -q img_align_celeba.zip
```

but I still get the same error - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Zip files aren't folders. Try unzipping first although you'll need to cd to the folder first - so something like this.

```
!cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/celeba
```

Then unzip

```
!yes|unzip -q img_align_celeba.zip -d img_align_celeba
```

Then this should work.

```
dataroot = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/celeba/img_align_celeba'
dataset = ImageFolder(root = dataroot, transform=transform)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew Chisholm - I've tried to run the first two commands you suggested however it throws the error: "unzip:  cannot find or open img_align_celeba.zip, img_align_celeba.zip.zip or img_align_celeba.zip.ZIP.
"

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce because I don't have access to your folder structure, so you will have to work at getting the exact path to your zip file correct for you.